# mongod doesn't start even on start of the system

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-14.04

when I run `sudo mongod` on my ubuntu 14.04 it gives below error

```
mongod --help for help and startup options
Tue Mar  7 09:42:15.992 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=2870 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db/ 64-bit host=keshav-mohta
Tue Mar  7 09:42:15.992 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.9
Tue Mar  7 09:42:15.992 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
Tue Mar  7 09:42:15.992 [initandlisten] build info: Linux orlo 3.2.0-58-generic #88-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 3 17:37:58 UTC 2013 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_54
Tue Mar  7 09:42:15.992 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
Tue Mar  7 09:42:15.992 [initandlisten] options: {}
Tue Mar  7 09:42:16.431 [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
Tue Mar  7 09:42:16.435 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Tue Mar  7 09:42:17.587 [websvr] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:28017
Tue Mar  7 09:42:17.587 [initandlisten] ERROR: listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
Tue Mar  7 09:42:17.587 [websvr] ERROR:   addr already in use
Tue Mar  7 09:42:17.587 [initandlisten] ERROR:   addr already in use
Tue Mar  7 09:42:17.587 [initandlisten] now exiting
Tue Mar  7 09:42:17.587 dbexit: 
Tue Mar  7 09:42:17.587 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Tue Mar  7 09:42:17.587 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Tue Mar  7 09:42:17.587 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Tue Mar  7 09:42:17.587 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Tue Mar  7 09:42:17.587 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Tue Mar  7 09:42:17.587 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Tue Mar  7 09:42:17.760 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Tue Mar  7 09:42:17.760 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Tue Mar  7 09:42:17.760 [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
Tue Mar  7 09:42:17.760 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
Tue Mar  7 09:42:17.969 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Tue Mar  7 09:42:17.969 dbexit: really exiting now
```

I know the solution to kill the process (`sudo killall mongod`) and then run the command again but my question is :

WHY it say *addr already in use* when I just start the system?

Is there any way so that I do not require to run 2 command on every morning to start mongod service.

---

#### UPDATE

my guess is that mongo service start on startup as I checked with

```
sudo initctl list | grep mongo
```

which output

> mongodb start/running, process 1190

now I execute below command to stop mongodb on startup

```
sudo update-rc.d -f mongodb remove
```

which output

> Removing any system startup links for /etc/init.d/mongodb ...

BUt it still display the mongodb in the list when check with `sudo initctl list`. even I start the system again to verify?

Comment: Can you check if there are 2 mongodb processes try to start on reboot?

Comment: I dontl know how one process is already running? my guess is something runs on startup of the system. How do we stop that?

Comment: list the mongo related processes on startup ls /etc/rc*.d|grep mongo. Remove one which is not required. sudo update-rc.d <unwanted mongo process> remove

Comment: `ls /etc/rc*.d| grep mongo` outputs nothing

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Sometimes starting the services in completely new terminal `ctrl + alt + T` works.

Step 2: Use `netstat` to detect the port is running or not

```
netstat -anp | grep mongodPortHere
```

If it is running then use `ps aux | grep "mongod" | less` for processId and use `kill -9 processId`

Comment: Check your system cron jobs in startup stop it

Comment: how to stop the startup script? see the update part of my question

Comment: Can  you try sudo `update-rc.d mongodb disable` ... I have found this http://edpflager.com/?p=2875 ... read "Disable the auto start of MongoDB". This might work. 
update me !

Comment: that's not working in my system. it gives *update-rc.d: warning:  start runlevel arguments (none) do not match mongodb Default-Start values (2 3 4 5)
update-rc.d: warning:  stop runlevel arguments (none) do not match mongodb Default-Stop values (0 1 6)
System start/stop links for /etc/init.d/mongodb do not exist.*

Comment: The above sudo update-rc.d -f mongodb remove might have removed mongodb from startup. Restart your pc again and try again.